# SQLite: Alternative for UPDATE JOIN subquery

Tags: sqlite

I have the following SELECT query in SQLite.  I'm struggling to figure out how to convert this to a SQLite-friendly UPDATE statement though...  I know SQLite UPDATE does not support JOIN. Thank you!

The query is finding the most recent/maximum date for each employee and adding a column with that date to each individual employee

```
SELECT
  emp.*, maxdate
FROM
  employees emp JOIN (
    SELECT name as newname, MAX(enddate) AS maxdate
    FROM
      employees
    GROUP BY name) m
  ON emp.name = m.newname
  ORDER BY maxdate DESC;
```

Comment: Could you please post an example of the output of the `SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN` query before and after the desired `UPDATE`? In other words, which fields would you like to update?

Comment: Not sure how to format this, but before the select query, the data looks like:
NAME     DATE
A             12/31/2016
A             1/31/2016
A             12/31/2015

afterwards, it looks like:
NAME     DATE            MAXDATE
A             12/31/2016  12/31/2016
A             1/31/2016    12/31/2016
A             12/31/2015  12/31/2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, if I understand correctly, what you want is

```
UPDATE employees
        SET enddate = (
             SELECT MAX(enddate)
                  FROM employees e2
                  WHERE e2.name = employees.name
             );
```